# 2019 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Esperanto Language's [first moderator election](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close and the two new moderators are:

[image: svendvn] [image: das-g]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Also, please join me in thanking Vanege and kristan who will be stepping down as moderator.

Since this was a [*pro tempore* election](https://esperanto.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211/announcing-a-pro-tempore-election) and there were just two nominees, it was ended without a vote.